Integration involving a random variable
How to approach this integral:
$$I(t) =  \int  A \cos(\alpha t + \phi (t))dt$$ where $A$ and $\alpha$ are constant?
$\phi (t)$ is modelled as a Wiener process (Gaussian distributed
random variable with a variance of $\sigma^2 $ and zero mean) and it acts as a noise source for the problem I am handling. Any help will be highly appreciated.

If $\phi(t)$ is a Wiener process then its variance grows linearly in time and is not a constant. Anyhow, if $\dot \phi(t)$ is a bandlimited white noise process with variance $\sigma^2$ (a constant) such that $\mathbf P [\dot \phi << \alpha] \approx 1$ then you can approximate the integrand as $\cos( \alpha t)-\phi \sin(\alpha t) $, which is what commsys engineers do, and the IEEEE has volumes written on this how to do,  when analyzing phase noise.

Might [math.se] be better suited for this math problem?

$I(t)$ is also a random process, and you can calculate the necessary averages, such as $\langle I(t)\rangle$, $\langle I(t)I(t')\rangle$, etc. It is useful to remember that $\cos(ix)=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$, which enables using the characteristic function of the process (or characteristic functional.)
Related: SDE with drift multiplied by telegraph like random process (with answers citing some relevant books.)
